# Php socket programming - ACK Server with 4 byte integer format

Tags: php, sockets, tcp, gps, byte

I am working on a GPS tracker project and created the socket server using this class

[How to listen to a TCP port using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054291/how-to-listen-to-a-tcp-port-using-php)

Its working fine till the 2nd step ACK of the number of the data received from the device.

This is what is exactly required by the integration document.

> Then module starts to send first AVL data packet. After server
> receives packet and parses it, server must report to module number of
> data received as integer (four bytes).
>
> If sent data number and reported by server doesn’t match module
> resends sent data.
>
> Server acknowledges data reception (3 data elements):    00000003 (3)
> Server ACK to AVL Data Packet

I am able to fully parse the data but unable to understand the way to send the integer in a 4 byte format but probably not getting sent the correct way.

I have tried [php pack()](https://www.php.net/pack)  with these formats i*, l*, L*

```
$output =pack('l*', $reply);
SocketServer::socket_write_smart($client->socket,$output); // Send the Client back the String
SocketServer::socket_write_smart($client->socket,"String? ",""); // Request Another String
```

$reply holds the number of the data sent as packet. I have tried to send 3 as integer or left padded 3 so that it becomes 0000003 (4 characters - 4 bytes)

But none of the formats was successful as the device is not sending me the next set of data.
Its mandatory that i send the number of data received as ACK to send back to get the next set if data from the device.

Can someone help me with the correct way so that i send the integer in the way so that its sent as 4 byte format.

Comment: Try `$output=pack('l', $reply)`. If it does not work, then try `$output=strrev(pack('l', $n))` (to change the endianness :)

Comment: $output =pack('N*', $reply); solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved on a similar question

[PHP convert integer to 32 bit (4 Byte) hex for socket programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26787898/php-convert-integer-to-32-bit-4-byte-hex-for-socket-programming)

Along with that

```
$output =pack('N*', $reply);
```

solved the issue.