# PHP convert integer to 32 bit (4 Byte) hex for socket programming

Tags: php, sockets, byte, pack, unpack

I need to convert integer to a 4 byte (32 bit) hex for sending it as ACK to a device i am currently trying to integrate.

For example

> 3 =  00000003
>   15 = 0000000F

Check http://www.mathsisfun.com/binary-decimal-hexadecimal-converter.html
1. Select signed 32 bit from the dropdown
2. Enter the value in decomal text box 
3. Check value in hex field.

I am using php pack function with this parameter but based on the response from the device, it does not seem to be the correct approach.

```
$reply = pack(L*,$num);
```

Is this the correct parameter or there is some other way.
Please suuggest.

Comment: make sure you're using the proper endianess/byte-order. `0xDEADBEEF` in PHP may very well need to be `0xEFBEADDE` on your device.

Comment: What are you getting? Also, in you actual code you have quotes around `L*`, right?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56786533/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-float-in-php) is how to convert byte array into float in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would do

```
$a = 15;
var_dump( sprintf("%08X", $a) );
$a = 3;
var_dump( sprintf("%08X", $a) );
```

this outputs

```
string(8) "0000000F"
string(8) "00000003
```

`08X` means make a 8 char string padded with `0` (if needed) with the argument being treated as hex. (Upper case letters)

so in your example

```
$reply = sprintf("%08X", $num)
```

Comment: I have tested your idea and it works exactly like i requested. In the mean time, i got the whole code running using $output =pack('N*', $reply); The server is running perfectly with this code and getting updated data too.

Comment: You dont actually need the * either.

Comment: What is the use of putting the *. I could not locate a good enough explanation anyw where. I assume that its converting all of the input numbers.