# How to receive TCP data (not HTTP) via PHP on WAMP/LAMP?

Tags: php, tcp, gps

I'm playing around with GPS Trackers and they send hex to a server via TCP. I've setup a LAMP server and would like to process and store data from trackers into mysql.

I've got tons of experience doing http web applications however I have zero experience playing w/ tcp sockets and processing data directly from it and not via HTTP, and dont know if that's possible.

1) I've read around and found support for TCP and stuff but my question is, can PHP alone process TCP data? I kinda thought PHP is on top of Apache HTTP only.

2) Also, if php does support direct TCP processing (or i guess i should say listening), is it "normally" supported by shared hosts? or do i have to request such feature?

3) Can you recommend an open-source package of some sort that can pretty much take care of receiving and storing raw data in mysql? All i really need is to get that data into mysql and i can do magic on it via php after.

PS
Do i even need to do this TCP way? I can change the PORT the device is sending to, and make it port 80. That way Apache will receive it and perhaps I can have an index.php file processing the raw data (? )

Hoping to find guidance and leads to get me started on the right path. :)

Comment: Did you read the selected answer on this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054291/how-to-listen-to-a-tcp-port-using-php  Also I believe shared web hosts are strictly for web/mail protocols, you may need VPS for it but it seems totally doable.

Comment: uh oh, i'm looking for the same thing, and it seems you can't do what you are thinking... 1) you'll find PHP as a cli process that can process your tcp data as a socket, sadly almost no hosting service will let you execute a PHP script directly... 2) uh, oh, I just said, nope, most host service will not let you do that... 3) i suggest you to look for a node.js server, (you can implement yours locally very easily) it let you create a server to listen to the TCP packets and to store to a mysql database, I read that godaddy let you set a node.js server but i'm still looking too...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for php, but with node.JS you can easily doing socket connection in web application using net. https://nodejs.org/api/net.html

You can receive the gps data and then convert to JSONObject and then diplay it on the map or something

Answer (score 0):

I think this linke ca help you .
In this link you see that writer create tcp socket and sent message to server and get reply from server :)

http://grassi86.altervista.org/client-tcp-with-php/