# Creating a listener socket for VTS in PHP

Tags: php, sockets, cakephp-2.3, ratchet

I have a listener running on the server in PHP. Its loosly based on link below but customized to my requirement.

[How to listen to a TCP port using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054291/how-to-listen-to-a-tcp-port-using-php)

of late when the number of vehicles have reached more than 150, the port is getting blocked.
When checking from Herculues Program its giving the following message

```
TCP connection error :10061
```

What is the most optimal method of creating a listener in PHP which can handle more than 1000 devices data at the same time.

I am looking at http://socketo.me/

Can anyone help me with past experience on the advantages/disadvantages for using Ratchet. The application is running in Cakephp

Answer (score 1):

I am running a Ratchet Websocket myself for about 10k concurrent users. 
It is running in 3 different processes connected to one pushserver that can send data to the right socket with the correct listeners(just to save bandwidth).

The highest delay I experience is 100ms.

The 3 processes are running in the Microsoft Azure Cloud, 1 in NA, 1 in the EU, 1 in Asia.

That way I am able to connect a user to the closest websocket I have.

I have no experience in Cakephp so I have no clue on how to implement it in that framework.

If you need any more information, please let me know.

Comment: Can you please share the code. I am to host it on a AWS and push it using SES

Comment: the setup that you have after following the tutorial from socketo.me will allow you to have one websocket, once you have a need for multiple websockets this will change.

Although by that time you might want to start saving WebSocket connections with their corresponding userId an to which of the(3in my cas) websockets it is connected in a table, that way doing the pushserver part should be easy.

tldr; follow the tutorial, start from there.